# How do I set CPU affinity while running a C code from Eclipse in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, affinity

I am able to do this from terminal using 'taskset -c 0 ./out'.
How can I do the same from Eclipse?

Comment: Why do you need affinity? Usually this is a sign of a bigger problem.

Comment: You can do the same from within the C code itself.  Look at sched_setaffinity() (Linux only) or pthread_setaffinity_np().

Comment: @StilesCrisis I can imagine various reasons for that. For example if you have a long calculation phase and don't want to have the thread shifted around the CPUs (which would have impact on your cache miss rate and hence calculation performance). The only "bigger problem" in that case is that you want to get maximum performance. But you are right: It could also be that the programmer did not take care of concurrency properly while crating multiple threads and got problems ob multi core machines now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
/* must be root to use these sched_function-----------------------*/

#define CPU_N 0 // affinity process




 void fix_affinity()
    {
      int error=0;
      cpu_set_t mask;
      /*  mask init  */
      CPU_ZERO(&mask);
      /* add CPU_N to  the mask */
      CPU_SET(CPU_N,&mask);

      /**
         test root access
      **/

      if(getuid()==0)
        {
          /*change affinity of process */
          error=sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&mask);
        }
      else
        {
          printf("must be root to change affinity\n");
        }
      if(error<0)
        {
          printf("sched_setaffinity() failed \n");
        }

    }
```

and just call it in your code

```
  fix_affinity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Run Configuration -> Arguments (tab)

Add

**/C "tasket -c 0 .\out"**